A 'negation-complement' in a topos is a pseudo-complement: a more direct proof than Goldblatt's?
Given a subobject $s\colon S \rightarrowtail X$, we define one sort of complement $\overline{s}\colon \overline{S} \rightarrowtail X$ in the usual way by pulling back $\top$ along $\neg\chi_s$ (or pulling back $\bot$ along $\chi_s$). Call this, to beg no questions, the 'negation-complement' of $s$.
In a topos, a negation-complement of $s$, so defined, is also a pseudo-complement of $s$ (so $r \cap s \leq\geq 0_X$ iff $r \leq \overline{s}$, for any $r\colon R \rightarrowtail X$, with $\leq$ the usual pre-order on monics.)
In Topoi, Goldblatt proves this at p. 180. (Well, strictly speaking he is dealing with subobjects redefined as equivalence classes of monics, but that's not significant for the following question.) The proof (in different notation) that (A), if $r \leq \overline{s}$ then $r \cap s \equiv 0_X$, is immediate. But his given proof of the other half, (B) if $r \cap s \equiv 0_X$ then $r \leq \overline{s}$, while elementary, seems at first blush surprisingly roundabout, inelegant and unintuitive (and long, when you unpack the lemmas/exercises he is calling on in the proof).
Question: Is there a neater, equally elementary but more intuitive, proof of (B) than Goldblatt's?

Well, you want to beg no questions but I think the efficiency of this result rather depends on how "$\neg$" is defined. To be sure, all definitions are equivalent but some give you what you want without much work.
Method $(1)$:

Define $\text{false}:1\to\Omega$ to be the classifying arrow of the zero subobject $!:0\hookrightarrow 1$. Further define $\neg:\Omega\to\Omega$ to be the classifying arrow of $\text{false}$. Here, we use that all arrows with domain $0$ or $1$ are monomorphisms.
Fix an object $X$ and two subobjects $A,B$. By the pullback lemma, we see $\neg B\hookrightarrow X$ is $\chi_B^{-1}(\text{false})$. Hence $A\subseteq\overline{B}$ if and only if $g:=\chi_B\circ\iota_A\overset{?}{=}\text{false}_A$. Again by the pullback lemma $A\cap B=0$ iff. $!:0\hookrightarrow A$ is $g^{-1}(\text{true})$. But you can realise $\text{false}_A$ has the same property; thus $\text{false}_A$ and $g$ classify the same subobject of $A$ (the zero one) if and only if $A\cap B=0$. But the definition of subobject classifier reduces this to $A\subseteq\neg B$ iff. $g=\text{false}_A$ iff. they both classify the same zero subobject iff. $A\cap B=0$.

Method $(2)$ (Mac Lane and Moerdijk):

By slice topos trickery, realise that $\mathrm{Sub}_{\mathcal{E}}(X)\simeq\mathrm{Sub}_{\mathcal{E}/X}(1)$ is a Heyting algebra for all $X\in\mathcal{E}$, such that all $f:Y\to X$ have $f^\ast$ a Heyting algebra homomorphism $\mathrm{Sub}_{\mathcal{E}}(X)\to\mathrm{Sub}_{\mathcal{E}}(Y)$. But that is to say $\mathcal{E}(-,\Omega)$ is a naturally varying Heyting algebra; we can Yoneda this to oblivion and infer the naturally preserved negations of all these algebras must come from a negation arrow $\neg:\Omega\to\Omega$ that, by definition !, serves as the Heyting negation for all $\mathcal{E}(X,\Omega)$. Since $\mathcal{E}(X,\Omega)\cong\mathrm{Sub}_{\mathcal{E}}(X)$ works using classifying arrows, it follows by definition that $\neg\circ\chi_B$ classifies $\neg B$ the Heyting pseudocomplement of $B$ in $X$, for any $X$ and any $B\subseteq X$.


Thanks for this. Though I wouldn't count Method (2) as "elementary". And Method (1) is I think, essentially, the proof idea which Goldblatt fully spells out. So maybe my question was misplaced: with intuition pumped along the lines you suggest, his proof is indeed natural enough.

@PeterSmith You're welcome. I don't have Goldblatt in front of me but in my eyes method $(1)$ is a fully self contained proof. We don't need to chase around a million exercises, it almost follows from the topos axioms directly. I agree method $(2)$ is less elementary but it is maybe the most natural way to define the internal logical manipulations (quite a lot follows from passing between these external-internal Heyting algebra correspondences) such as $\neg$, and my point was just to highlight that if you've defined it "correctly" then the question is easily settled.

I'm not sure how we assess "it almost follows from the topos axioms directly"! Perhaps we could continue via email? -- my address is at the bottom of the "about" page of logicmatters.net .
